# How do I change the payload URL in the Network tab to my personal domain?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, localhost, adsense

Network tab - URL of payload is local host.
I want to change this to my personal website domain.
I'm using react and aws, how do I fix it? Help me, i'm super beginner

This is to get ads from Google AdSense normally.
Everything is approved by Google AdSense, and there are no policy violations.

I've been looking for it and I think this localhost is the problem.
My code doesn't have anything for that localhost. I don't know where it went wrong.

Should we use environmental variables?
I want my personal domain to be displayed in that URL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Urie.png)